# Eclipse build 2020-0615-1200 (4.16) thinks my Java compiler compliance level is set to 1.5 or less, but it isn't, it is set to 1.8

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors

I am using Eclipse build 2020-0615-1200 (4.16), and Java 1.8.0_261-b12.

I have two projects with working code that I created on my PC. I copied both projects to my Google Drive so I can access them on my laptop. When I imported the first project to my laptop about a week ago, it worked fine. Today I imported the second project, and I get over a hundred messages like this:

```
    '<>' operator is not allowed for source level below 1.7
    Cannot refer to the non-final local variable path defined in an enclosing scope
    Cannot refer to the non-final local variable path defined in an enclosing scope
    Incorrect number of arguments for type HashMap<K,V>; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <>
    Method references are allowed only at source level 1.8 or above
    Resource specification not allowed here for source level below 1.7
    Syntax error, 'for each' statements are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater
    Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater
    Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater
    Syntax error, varargs are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater
```

I have tried resetting and redefining the compiler compliance level to min and max, no change.
This exact same code compiles and works perfectly on my PC.

Adthanksvance

Chris

Comment: Are you setting these values in the project or in the workspace?

Comment: I am setting them in the project. I have been using Eclipse since the first release.

Comment: When the projects were copied to Google Drive, were both of their `.settings` folders included?